# How to quit my main method?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, program-entry-point

This is my main method.I have an ArrayList for both herbivores and my plants in a canvas size of (1000 x 1000) What I have them do is: 
All the herbivores eat a plant that is closest to them. 
What I know need to do is once all the plants have been eaten, they main method should quit and print some statistics. What I understand is I need to quit before my Herbivores start looking for the next plant because it would then give me an error because the arrayList would now be empty. However, if I use "System.exit(0);" before my findNearestWithinFiftyMeters method then it would execute the rest of my code. How do I make it quit but still print my statistics?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Set the canvas size to (1000,1000) and x and y scale to (0,1000)
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(1000,1000);
        StdDraw.setXscale(0.0 , 1000.0);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0.0 , 1000.0);

        //ArrayList for the Plants
        ArrayList<Plant> thePlants = new ArrayList<Plant>();
        //Create 300 Plants

        for (int i=0; i<300; i++){
            thePlants.add(new Plant (1000 * Math.random(),1000 * Math.random()));
        }



        //ArrayList for the Herbivores
        ArrayList<Herbivore> theHerbivores = new ArrayList<Herbivore>();
        //Create 20 Herbivores
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
            theHerbivores.add(new Herbivore (1000 * Math.random(), 1000 * Math.random()));
        }

        //Draw Graphics:
        while(theHerbivores.size() > 0){
            //Clears the board
            StdDraw.clear();

            //created Herbivores of size
            for(int i=0; i<theHerbivores.size(); i++){  
                //Draws the herbivore at position i
                theHerbivores.get(i).draw();

                if(thePlants.size() == 0){
                 StdDraw.clear();
                }

                //Finds the plant that is closest to the herbivore
                Plant closest = findNearestWithinFiftyMeters(thePlants , theHerbivores.get(i));
                if(closest != null){
                    //IF the closest plant is NOT null then move towards closest plant
                    theHerbivores.get(i).moveToward(closest.getX(), closest.getY() );
                    //now that we have the closest plant in regards to this herbivore
                    //we want it to move to the plant
                    theHerbivores.get(i).createRandomTarget();
                    //Reset the target each time it finds a new plant to chew
                }
                else{
                    //if it IS null
                    //Walk in a random direction (towards the imaginary plant)
                    theHerbivores.get(i).move();
                }
            }

            //Draws plants
            for(Plant p: thePlants){
                p.draw();
            }

            //Check for any herbivores that have moved off screen
            for(int i=0; i < theHerbivores.size(); i++){
                //if an herbivore moved too far left or right move to other side of screen
                if(theHerbivores.get(i).getX()>1000){
                    theHerbivores.get(i).setX(0);
                }
                else if(theHerbivores.get(i).getX()<0){
                    theHerbivores.get(i).setX(1000);
                }               
                //if an herbivore moved too far up or down
                if(theHerbivores.get(i).getY()>1000){
                    theHerbivores.get(i).setY(0);
                }
                else if(theHerbivores.get(i).getY()<0){
                    theHerbivores.get(i).setY(1000);
                }
            }


            //looping through all the plants to remove plants that have been eaten
            for(int i=0; i< theHerbivores.size(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < thePlants.size(); j++){
                    if(thePlants.get(j).distanceTo(theHerbivores.get(i).getX(),theHerbivores.get(i).getY()) < 3){

                        thePlants.remove(j);

                        theHerbivores.get(i).eat();
                        //INCREMENT HERBIVORE EATEN COUNT
                    }
                }
                StdDraw.show(1);

            }
            stepCounter++;
        }//end while loop

        System.out.println(stepCounter + " steps done in this simulation");
        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println(estimatedTime + "Length of time simulation used" );
        for(int i=0; i<theHerbivores.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Herbivore # " + i + "X: " + theHerbivores.get(i).getX() + "Y: " + theHerbivores.get(i).getY() + " EATEN: "+ theHerbivores.get(i).getEatCount());
        }

        return;
    } // end of main method


    static long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
    static int stepCounter = 0;

    public static Plant findNearestWithinFiftyMeters(ArrayList<Plant> thePlants , Herbivore eater){
        //plant variable for storage to find closest plant to that herbivore
        Plant closest = thePlants.get(0);
        for(int i=0; i<thePlants.size(); i++){
            if(eater.distanceTo(closest.getX(), closest.getY()) > eater.distanceTo(thePlants.get(i).getX(),thePlants.get(i).getY()) ){
                //if the plant in closest variable is farther away than the 
                //plant in index 'i' then replace the plant in closest with the plant in index 'i'
                closest = thePlants.get(i);
            }
        }

        if(eater.distanceTo(closest.getX(),closest.getY()) > 50){
            //if distance is greater than 50(herbivore sight range) then set closest equal to null
            closest=null;
        }
        return closest;
    }   
} // end of class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is **not** to quit your `main` method, but to exit the loop of the eating action in order to print some statistics. A good way to do this is alter your loop condition so that it terminates when not needed:

```
while(theHerbivores.size() > 0 && thePlants.size() > 0) {
 //Rest of code....
}
```

This will lead to the execution of the rest of your code after the outter loop.

As an addition to your question, you can use a `break` statement to get outside a loop when needed, usually used in combination with a conditional `if/else if/else` statement inside the loop. `System.exit(0)` will lead to the actual force of your program termination, which is **not** what you want in your case, as aforementioned.

Comment: Thank you! that makes so much sense!

Comment: You are welcome. Consider voting the answer as best if you think it is one, or upvoting it when you can.

Answer (score 1):

You could alter your while loop to only run while there are herbivores and plants.

```
while(theHerbivores.size() > 0 && thePlants.size() > 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to my understanding, you are trying to print some information after your main method ends without terminating the entire program. If this is correct, you should just create a method that prints these statistics. Then call on this method at the end of the main method. That way, the main method ends after calling on this method but the program continues to run until the statistics are printed.

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //everything in the main method
    //the end of the main method
    printStatistics();
    //main method terminates here but the program runs until the printStatistics() method finishes running
}

private void pintStatistics() {
    System.out.println(/*insert statistics here*/);
    //entire program terminates here
}
```